# TDD assumes interfaces are defined already; how to cope?

Tags: tdd

To write tests before code, you need to have a way to interface with the code. Tests tend to define interfaces well ahead of time so that tests can just be written.

But often developing a good implementation involves inventing a set of good inter-component interfaces, tweaking and remaking these interfaces many times. During this you either keep on rewriting good portions of test code, or allow tests to lag behind code.

Are there any best practices to alleviate this?

Comment: I struggled a lot with this, as I tried to get into test-driven development before I had much experience with any sort of programming. I eventually figured that testing can confirm that code works as you expect, but it can’t check that you’ve got a good design, and if your design changes as your code develops (as it probably will), you’ll just have to rewrite some tests. I guess that encourages paying a lot of attention to the design of the code, which is a good thing. It might be a good idea in some cases to do a throwaway prototype, without tests, to work through the interface design first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds like the whole red-green-refactor loop. That is to say, TDD *is* - sort of - about this rewriting of interfaces. This keeps them lean and to the point. Once you get the hang of TDDing, and you write your tests interface-oriented and keep your objects small you shouldn't see much changing going on unless you hit on something unforseen and must adapt, which is the point of being agile (which is hopefully why you're TDDing)

It sounds sort of like you're defining whole interfaces in one go, though. Which would be wrong. One test should generate one function in the interface, and it's expected behavior. Your interface will grow with the test-suite, thereby minimizing further any back-patching.

Answer (score 5):

Just as you write tests *as if* the code you are testing were already written, you can (and should) write them as if the interface were already written.  That is the **Design** part - the most important part - of **Test-Driven Design**.  You know what functionality you are about to ask for from your class under test; write the test as if that functionality were already there.  The names and parameters you use now, in your test; what naturally occurs to you, thinking as a client of the code and interface being tested; these elements feature prominently in the design of your class and its interface.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to @Per Fagrell -s "Interface will grow over time".

Alternative: if you are creating businessclasses with broad functionality how about defining multible interfaces for different aspects or subfeatures

Answer (score 0):

The failing unit test is not only the checks failed. Failed unit test compilation can also be considered as a failed test. Therefore, write your unit tests as the interfaces are there.

TDD - test driven design - design means changing the interfaces.